# Show hide div (video) on keypress

Tags: javascript, html, toggle, keypress

I m trying to hide/show video when pressing a keyboard button but can't make it work

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="toggle.js"></script>
<div id="video">
  <video src="assets/knights.mp4" class="video" style="" id="video" loop="loop" muted="muted" autoplay="autoplay"></video>
</div>
```

togggle.js

```
$(document).keypress(function(e){
var key = e.which;
if (key == 116) {
    // if the user pressed 't':
    $('div').toggle();
}
});
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cy8xw144/1/ what is not working?

Comment: i have a feel that you didn't include jquery....

Comment: thanks both :) solved  Any way to start the playback when pressing the keyboard button?